# Convert slicers into drop down menus

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a 5 columns with 1000's of rows.

First column contains dates, the next house names, the next door numbers etc.

I have created slicers to easily filter through the data which is very helpful.

However, what I am after are drop down menus.

How do I convert the slicers into a series of drop down menus which are dependent on each other? I know how to create basic drop down menus, however my data is too large to do is using the named range task.

Comment: It's not clear what you're using to create this UI.

Comment: HI @Emyr I use excel 2010! I just created a pivot table and then added slicers! Any help would be greatly appreciated